# Adding new row to HTML table dynamically with JScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am writing a code in HTML + Jquery and need to add rows to a table dynamically.

I've written the code to add the rows dynamically, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my JScript code :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "date";
            element1.name="datebox[];
            element1.id = "dt";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "select";
            element2.name = "selectbox[]";
            element2.id = "slct";
            cell2.appendChild(element2);

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            var element3 = document.createElement("input");
            element3.type = "text";
            element3.name = "txtbox[]";
            element3.id = "txt";
            cell3.appendChild(element3);
            table.appendChild(cell1);
        }
    </script>
```

This is my Table:

```
<table id = "tab" style="width:500px">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Treatment Goal</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><INPUT type="date" name="datebox[]" id = "dt"/></td>
        <td>
            <SELECT name="selectbox[]" id = "slct">
            </SELECT>
        </td>
        <td><INPUT type="text" name="txtbox[]" id = "txt"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am calling the function in the onClick event of a button like this :

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="+" name="Add" onclick="addRow('tab')"/>
```

The html page doesn't respond to the click event and nothing happens.
Cannot understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLZSx/)**

The first problem is a syntax error on this line (you didn't close the double quote):

```
element1.name="datebox[];
                        ^ missing "
```

The second problem is you are appending the cell to the table which is wrong, you should be appending the row:

```
table.appendChild(row);
                  ^ changed to row from cell
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a quotation mark on the line:

```
element1.name="datebox[];
```

after the name element.